# Databases Synchronization – best practice

Tags: sql-server-2008, synchronization

We have live and stand-by database servers.  Both are SQL Server 2008 databases and hosted on Windows Server 2003.

May I know the best practice that people follow to synchronize the 2 databases (live and stand-by) so that we could make sure the stand-by server up whenever the live server is down for any reason.

It would be great if you could also provide a reference document or web references (if needed).

Comment: Perhaps review answers to your questions and accept some?

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar using Replication Services(within SQL Server).

[Startup guide can be found here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[From the MS SQL Server 2008 "High Availability—Always On" page](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/high-availability.aspx)

For a [list of solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx)...

All solutions are used somewhere. We use clustering for example.

Answer (score 0):

On top of my head, available solutions in SQL Server 2008 are Clustering, Replication, Log Shipping and Database Mirroring when dealing with high availability. Also worth mentioning that it does not replace a disaster recovery plan which also involves backups, etc.